# How to export texture after editing nodes/uv

Tags: texturing, node-editor, uv-image-editor

i am new to blender but i can do few basic things..i want to create a texture for a football kit with model extracted from a game..

i have base texture produced with image editor (ps)

[image: initial layout]
[image: desired result]

how can i export texture then i'll fix the rest in image editor
i cant modify model because that is the model the game understands

Thanks

Comment: i still dont get it...baking error (loop found)

Comment: anyways i could send the model and texture to work on then post directions afterwards....thanks anyways

Answer (score 1):

I think it would be easier to adjust UV map, then to change distorted texture, but you can do that, by baking Diffuse color to new texture, then exporting it as an image.Like this:[image]

Below you will see, how it needs to be done in Blender Internal in your particular example.As the shirt is made out of 3 different models, I joined them for baking purpose, after that you won't need the duplicate, so you can delete it, cause If the game expects 3 meshes as a shirt input, then probably exporting 1 mesh will not work.
[image]

Comment: Pls can anyone help me work on the file(i'l send tru email)..then later post how it was exported..cos I might av changed somethings I shouldnt av done..thanks

Comment: You have to pay closer attention to the gif. The texture node, with new texture (Untitled.001) is not connected to the Shader, while baking.It just needs to be selected, before hitting bake, for blender to know on which texture you want to bake.

Comment: OK..I opened gif wit PS and folowd each slide..am new so maybe I have set somethings I should not have..I don't mind sending the file if you can help me check and then you tell what I actually did wrong..I really appreciate

Comment: If you followed all the steps and still didn't get expected outcome, send the file via [Blend-Exchange](http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/). I'll check it and let you know, what's wrong.

Comment: @ Mzidare #Texture didn't attach to Blend-Exchange so i zipped both .blend file and texture and then i changed extension from .zip to .blend...you can easily change extension back to .zip and extract both files

Comment: [<img src="http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=2193" />](http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/2193/)

Comment: I updated the answer with more info and here is your file with new texture:         [<img src="http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=2195" />](http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/2195/)

Comment: Thanks...i've seen model but your baked texture didnt come out the way I want..

Comment: What am trying to acheive is just the neck mapping...the mesh shuld remain d default way after exporting texture which means texture is to change from vertical lines in the neck texture to screwd lines...jst like using texture paint on a rough mesh

Comment: Then do it only for the neck. What's the problem?

Answer (score 0):

If you are getting the 'loop' error while baking, this means your target image to bake the result to is the same image you're using to bake from.

To resolve this problem, make a new image of the desired size and set it active in the "UV/image editor" viewer by going in to edit mode of your object and opening this image.